# JPA 2.0 and MySQL binary field and where clause

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have problem with fetching from MySQL table with "binary(16)" (UUID converted to binary) field.

```
TypedQuery<T> q = em.createQuery(String.format("SELECT bob FROM %s bob WHERE bob.buid = ?1", cls.getSimpleName()), cls);
byte[] bbuid = decodeBUIDString(buid);
q.setParameter(1, bbuid);

return q.getSingleResult();
```

When i do this it fails with Warning. That "==" can not be done on ArrayExpression and ArrayLiteral.

Any idea?

This is the warning i get and empty result

```
[INFO] WARNING: Cannot perform operation "==" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ArrayExpression@7971d4d7 and org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ArrayLiteral@4e69d64f
```

Entity is actualy MappedSuperClass because some of tables use same binary id.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BUIDEntityObject extends EntityObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BUIDEntityObject.class.getSimpleName());

    @Column(columnDefinition="BINARY(16) NOT NULL")
    protected byte[] buid; //identifications

    public byte[] getBuid() {
        return this.buid;
    }

    public String getStringBUID(){
        return Hex.encodeHexString(getBuid());
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBUIDString(String buid) {
        try {
            return Hex.decodeHex(buid.toCharArray());
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void setBuid(byte[] buid) {
        this.buid = buid;
    }
}
```

**Edit #4:**

I forgot to mention that i use Datanucleaus 3.1.3 and Google App Engine.

**Edit #5:**

I ported to Hibernate. Now it works :P

Comment: what type is the build param?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to define. It is byte[]. JPA saves and loads buid colum without a problem. The byte array is actualy UUID in binary form.

Comment: why do you decode build? and not use bbuild?

Comment: Huh i see the problem. Its a typo while i was trying to figure the problem. It doesnt work nither with the bbuid nor buid. The buid is the hex string.

Comment: okay. Could you also provide the entity?

Comment: Ok i added the entity. The entity is actually mapped super class. It is used to add binary secondary Id. Which is gona get exposed to external Web endpoints.

Comment: Because of the array type jpa expects it to be used in an IN cause. Try to pass the binary value as a String.

Try using Arrays.toString(...)

Comment: When i try to set any kind of string to parameter i get this

[INFO] WARNING: Parameter 1 needs to be assignable from [B yet the value is of type java.lang.String

Comment: I kind of fixed the problem by migrating to Hibernate :D